# Memoir: align multiple figures using subbottom

Tags: memoir, subfloats, minipage

I have 4 subfigures in a 2x2 matrix, where the figures on the left are legends with varying widths and those on the right are plots of equal widths.  I would like to have the figures in the 1st column left-aligned, and those on the right centered.

I'm using the Memoir class. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering

        \subbottom[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
        \subbottom[Fig. B]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
        \subbottom[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
        \subbottom[Fig. B]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

        \caption{Left-align the `A's and center the `B's}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here's the figure upon compilation:
[image]

**Bonus:**
Get rid of the labels (a) and (c), and renumber the labels (b) and (d) to (a) and (c), respectively.

**Another option** would be using minipages within the figure environment, but the figures are numbered anew if I do this. The MWE for this case:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{This is a very very very long caption for figure 1}

        \vspace*{5mm}

        \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{This is a very very very long caption for figure 2}
    \end{minipage}

    \caption{Outer caption}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which when compiled looks like this:
[image]

See how instead of `Figure 0.3(a)` and `Figure 0.3(b)`, they are numbered as independent figures instead of subfigures.

Please let me know how I can solve this problem.

Thanks,
Kavi

Answer (score 1):

The OP is probably not interested as this is an old question. Though I had to find a solution since I was facing the same issue.

The `{minipage}` solution as the OP suggests works to an extent, we can remove the subcation labels (a) and (c), left align the 1st column figures and center the 2nd ones. MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \end{minipage}\hfill
            \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
        \subbottom[Fig. B]{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
        \subbottom[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
            \end{minipage}

        \caption{Left-align the `A's and center the `B's}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Solution with minipage]

But A and B are not vertically aligned...

To get the aligment the OP wants 1st and 2nd row v-centered, 1st column left aligned and 2nd column center aligned we can use a `{tabular}` environment along with the `valign` option introduced by `ajustbox`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lc}
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} &\subbottom[Fig. B]{%
            \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}}\\
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} &\subbottom[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}}\\
            \end{tabular}
        \caption{Left-align the `A's and center the `B's}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution with tabular]